# How to ignore the effect of leap year when using Temporal.Duration?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to compare the duration of `x` and the duration of a year in second, to find out how many times I need to repeat an action annually.

I get the seconds of a year like this:

```js
const now = Temporal.Now.zonedDateTimeISO('Europe/London')

Temporal.Duration.from("P1Y").total({ relativeTo: now, unit: "seconds"}) //31536000
```

And I get the duration of `x` like that as well, but when `x` is `P2Y`, I get an extra `86400`, as next year(2024) is a leap year, which we have 29/2

```js
Temporal.Duration.from("P2Y").total({ relativeTo: now, unit: "seconds"}) //63158400, instead of 6307200
```

I want to ignore Leap Year in the duration(I know the result will be incorrect, but I want a more theoretical result), how can I do that?

Comment: You can check if the year is a leap year and subtract the difference from the result. Also if you already know how much seconds there are in a year why are you calculating it?

So maybe I didn't understand your problem?

Comment: but what if a duration spans between two leap years? checking a boolean would not help? It is a simplified example there, I was expecting user to input something like `P2Y3M4D`, so it is not just year

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Calculate how many times the action can be repeated until the input date?